# "AttributeError:" After converting script to TF2

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I used to the automatic update script but am still running into some issues. This area seems to be the part which is causing the issues, any help would be appreciated.

Error issued:" AttributeError: 'BatchDataset' object has no attribute 'output_types' "

```
# network parameters
n_hidden_1 = 50
n_hidden_2 = 25


ds_train = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_placeholder, Y_placeholder)).shuffle(buffer_size=round(len(X_train) * 0.3)).batch(batch_size_placeholder)

ds_test = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X_placeholder, Y_placeholder)).batch(batch_size_placeholder)

ds_iter = tf.compat.v1.data.make_one_shot_iterator(ds_train.output_types, ds_train.output_shapes)

next_x, next_y = ds_iter.get_next()

train_init_op = ds_iter.make_initializer(ds_train)
test_init_op = ds_iter.make_initializer(ds_test)
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
ds_train.output_types
```

with:

```
tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_types(ds_train)
```

similarly you may need `tf.compat.v1.data.get_output_shapes(ds_train)`